# A django problem that doesn't show up in runserver

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In runserver, I can view my website no problems. (viewing it through lynx on the same machine)

But when I view the same thing through apache, (passenger) I get an error like the following:

```
Could not import PROJ.APP.views Error was: No module named PROJ.views
```

It looks like a problem with the urlconf, but again that is the same between both runserver and not.

I have disabled admin & admin autodiscovery.

I have killed all running python instances & deleted all .pyc files.  I don't use any {% url %} tags in any templates.

The question is in general, what type of things could be causing this?

**solved** it was a problem of relative imports. In some files I was importing APP.models instead of PROJ.APP.models.

Comment: Your apache config is most likely wrong, please paste it.

Comment: it was a problem of relative imports.  In some files I was importing APP.models instead of PROJ.APP.models.  I don't know how runserver was getting around it.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is how it's gotten around.  Please post your Apache configuration so we can see your `PYTHONPATH` setting.

Comment: Please post your (self-found) solution as answer and accept it. That will mark the question as answered (which can't hurt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

It was a problem of relative imports. In some files I was importing APP.models instead of PROJ.APP.models.

The error wasn't giving any indication of which file was causing the problem.  Once I changed all of them it was fine.  Thanks, guys.